# How to check if Contacts are Merged using Google Contacts API?

Tags: android, ios, google-contacts-api

We have developed (iOS & Android) client application that can interact with Google's contact lists. We are doing various operations like Add/ Update/ Delete Contact, etc.

However we are facing one prolem when Contacts are Merged. Google Calendar API does provide final (Merged) Contact in API response. It also tells the contact to be deleted.

However the problem is, **How to identify if this response is a result of Merged Contact operation.** Normally when Contacts are deleted / updated we are getting similar API response. Thus from Response XML it doesn't seem to identify if Contacts are Merged?/which contact got removed(merged to other).

Can anyone spread a light over this trouble?

Comment: Is the `ContactId` the same in both the first and the 2nd contact after merging?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0: No both ids are different. It gives all details for both contacts for one contact status deleted (gd:deleted & _deleted:true) & other _deleted:false. That doesn't explain if it's result of Contact Merge. It could also be like: One contact edited & one contact deleted independently. No sign to identify if it's Merge contact.